# PyQt application runs fine if executed from IDLE, but reports 'No Module Named xxx' from Command Line

Tags: python, pyqt, python-idle

Is there a special setup needed to run a gui application from the command line  (i.e. python pyqtapp.py) ?

When I run it from the dos prompt it complains about the modules in my .py file.. like 'no module named winreg'.    Yet it executes fine under Idle.

It seems like it's a path issue, but the Windows enviroment path is set correctly.. especially since I have no problem running the script from within the IDLE ide.   I know I should probably be using a more professional IDE like pycharm, but IDLE seems to work well enough so I haven't changed.. Unless it's CAUSING an issue with the command line working?

What could cause this?

Comment: try PYTHONPATH, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-7

Comment: Setting enviroment variables (PATH, PYTHONPATH and PYHOME) to 'C:\Python34;C:\Python34\Lib;C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages' didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/_winreg.html i think your python version in idle is python 3, and command line is python 2.

Comment: Please don't hide crucial information when asking a quesiton.  What is 'xxx' really?  Also, try `import sys; print(sys.path)` both in Idle and command line and see what is difference and if 'xxx' is related to difference.

Comment: @Terry The reason I put xxx is because it changes depending on what package I import first, if I move import queue to the top it'll say no module named queue, etc, etc.      It seems to be a general import module issue rather than a specific module problem.

Comment: @Terry,   Almost forgot printing sys.path does show a different output from Idle and the command line!  The command line looks totally different (and maybe not even properly formed!).   Where does it get it from, and/or how to I force it to use the same path that IDLE is using?